# How to delay my javascript code until a JSON file is loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, loading

I have a web application built with jQuery, and I need to load some JSON data *before* anything else is done. Currently, I'm doing it like this:

```html
<html>
  ...
  <script type="text/javascript">
    // Load the data (directly injected into the HTML)
    var json = { ... };

    // Once the full DOM is loaded, do whatever I need
    $(whatever);

    function whatever() { ... }
  </script>
  ...
</html>
```

It works, but it's extremely ugly. I'd rather load the actual JSON file, for example using jQuery's [`getJSON`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON) with a callback function. But calling AJAX functions in a synchronous way isn't allowed anymore ([at least with jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)). So... how do I make sure that my `whatever` method isn't called until that callback has finished?

Just calling `$(whatever)` from my callback function is not an option, because I actually have many of those `$()` distributed across the different pages of the application.

Comment: Why would `I actually have many of those $() distributed across the different pages of the application.` stop you from using the callback? You could in each callback test if all the files you needed had loaded.

Comment: If the object is trustworthy, I think I would prefer your `var json = { ... };` version, if possible - one less network request means slightly less time for the site's scripts to activate. If it's injected with PHP, for example, and you don't like `var json = <?php echo ...`, you can put the JSON into a `script` tag with a custom type instead and then parse its `textContent`. Also note that there's no such thing as a JSON object - JSON is a *string notation*. A string can be JSON, but an object never is, so you might call the variable something like `data` rather than `json`

Comment: "*I have many of those [callbacks]*" - just add a callback to *this* call `$.getJSON(url).done(function(json) { whatever(json); });` - or are you saying you load the json all over the place?  Or that all your doc.ready's rely on that json being preloaded?  If so, instead of using a doc.ready, use listen for a custom event and raise the event on the $.getJSON handler.  Or replicate the doc ready and call it when json loaded.

Comment: @CertainPerformance yes, it is injected - with Node.js. I already tried moving it to its own script tag, but then I ran into caching problems. As for the `json` variable, I just named that for the example, it's actually called `data` in my code :)

Comment: @mplungjan ok, I can test if the needed files are loaded. But what if they aren't, how do I wait until they are? I can only think of polling with a setTimeout, but that would be messy...

Comment: @freedomn-m yes, the doc.ready rely on the JSON. It's a templated application, I load the JSON once for every page, in the header, and then depending of the URL, I build a template or another, which mean different HTML blocks, different javascript files, each of which may have a `$(function)` to be executed after the DOM is loaded. A custom event sounds promising, I'll look into that

Comment: @freedomn-m you were right. I've managed to implement it using a custom event (I didn't know they even existed), combined with document.ready. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found two different ways to implement it. First, **using the [`.holdReady()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.holdReady/) function** in jQuery:

> The `$.holdReady()` method allows the caller to delay jQuery's `ready` event. This *advanced feature* would typically be used [...] to load [...] before allowing the ready event to occur

So in my case, the code should look like this:

```html
<html>
  ...
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var json = {};
    $.holdReady(true);
    $.getJSON(url, '', function(data) {
      json = data;
      $.holdReady(false);
    });

    $(whatever);
  </script>
  ...
</html>
```

**Another option, using [custom events](https://learn.jquery.com/events/introduction-to-custom-events/)** (thanks to *freedomn-m*'s suggestion in the comments), would be something like this:

```html
<html>
  ...
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var json = {};
    // Request the JSON file
    $.getJSON(url, '', function(data) {
      // When it's retrieved, store the data in the `json` variable
      json = data;
      // And when the DOM is ready...
      $(function() {
        // ...trigger the custom `jsonReady` event
        $(document).trigger('jsonReady');
      });
    });
  </script>
  ...
</html>
```

The only change required is to replace all the `$(whatever);` for `$(document).on('jsonReady', whatever);`.

Comment: Why not declare `whatever` as a function and call it in the `$.getJSON` callback?

Comment: Because "Just calling $(whatever) from my callback function is not an option, because I actually have many of those $() distributed across the different pages of the application."

Comment: callback are the way to go. you may need to design/organize your app logic better,

Answer (score 1):

There is a simpler way of doing things ;)

```js
let json = {}
$(document).ready(() => {
  function whatever() {
    // do some stuff
    console.log('run the program');
  }
  $.getJSON('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users', (data) => {
      json = data;
      console.log(json);
    })
    .then(() => whatever());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Some paragraph</p>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Unfortunately, in my case that wouldn't work. It's a templated web application, I load the JSON file at the very beginning, at the header. Then, depending of the URL, it loads different HTML blocks, meaning different `whatever` functions. One page might have only one of those functions, another could have 2 or 3. It would be a nightmare to invert the execution order and call all of them from the getJSON callback.